# Android, SQLite, извлечение строк и вывод через текст

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Учебное приложение. Создаю базу данных
Вот сам класс базы:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {
    // имя базы данных
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
    // версия базы данных
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // имя таблицы
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "aboonents";
    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    public static final String SECOND_NAME = "Second_name";
    public static final String PATRONYMIC = "Patronymic";
    public static final String REGION = "Region";
    public static final String ARREARS = "Arrears";
    public static final String CONSUMPTION = "Consumption";
    public static final String PHONE = "Phone";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            FIRST_NAME  + " text not null, " +
            SECOND_NAME  + " text not null, " +
            PATRONYMIC + " text not null, " +
            REGION  + " text not null, " +
            ARREARS  + " text not null, " +
            CONSUMPTION  + " text not null, " +
            PHONE + " integer);";

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                          int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Создание базы и занесение значений.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edit_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_1);
    text_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.FIRST_NAME, "firstname");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.SECOND_NAME, "secondname");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.PATRONYMIC, "patronymic");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.REGION, "region");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.ARREARS, "arrears");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.CONSUMPTION, "consumption");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.PHONE , "phone");
    mSqLiteDatabase.insert("db1", null, values);
```

Далее, после нажатия кнопки:

```
case R.id.button_2:

    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("cats", new String[]
                    {       DatabaseHelper.FIRST_NAME,
                            DatabaseHelper.SECOND_NAME,
                            DatabaseHelper.PATRONYMIC,
                            DatabaseHelper.REGION,
                            DatabaseHelper.ARREARS,
                            DatabaseHelper.CONSUMPTION,
                            DatabaseHelper.PHONE},
            null, null,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String firstname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.FIRST_NAME));
    String secondname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SECOND_NAME));
    String patronymic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PATRONYMIC));
    String region = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.REGION));
    String arrears = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ARREARS));
    String consumption = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CONSUMPTION));
    String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PHONE));

    text_1.setText(firstname);
    cursor.close();
    break;
```

Ловлю ошибку =(

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.xxxxxxxx.admin.the_address_book, PID: xxxx
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Уже второй день как не могу разобраться, как работать с базами данных=(

Comment: Ваша проблема не имеет отношения к SQLLite и связана ,видимо, с тем, что вы в разметке указали атрибут onClick но не реализовали его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот этот кусок кода

```
Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("cats", new String[]
{       
    DatabaseHelper.FIRST_NAME,
```

У тебя обращение к таблице `cats` идет, а в коде инициализации я не вижу создание таблицы `cats`. Если я прав, то вместо `cats` должно быть `db1`

Comment: В запросе указывается таблица для выборки, а не база. Вы саму ошибку читали?

Comment: Да, так всё и было. Стоит формировать вопросы с утра, а не вечером.

Answer (score -1):

Может не стоит работать напрямую с SQLite, она тяжелая для новичков. Можно воспользоватся более простыми библиотеками которые дадут вам даже больше возможностей чем SQLite. Например:

[Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/)

[Green DAO](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO)

пожалуй самая простая из них [OrmLite](http://OrmLite)

можете еще почитать этот [пост](https://habrahabr.ru/company/yotadevices/blog/242559/)